# Filtering two columns: keep all the rows associated to one ID if exists a value in the second column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a table with various columns but i need to filter it based on two, the table structure is the following:

```
ID    Test     
1     A
1     B
1     C
2     B
2     D
3     A
4     A
4     C
4     D
5     B
5     C
```

What i need to do is keeping all rows associated to one ID if exists the case where the test is "A", the filtered table should then be:

```
ID    Test     
1     A
1     B
1     C
3     A
4     A
4     C
4     D
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use:

```
=FILTER(A1:B11,COUNTIFS(A1:A11,A1:A11,B1:B11,"A"))
```

[image]

---

Or, based on your comment:

```
=LET(X,COUNTIFS(B1:B11,B1:B11,L1:L11,"A"),INDEX(FILTER(B1:L11,X),SEQUENCE(SUM(X)),{1;11}))
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but what if those two colums arent sequential? Like i have the IDs in column B and the values in column L?

Comment: @Piazza, see the edit. I'm not a 100% sure about the semicolon in `{1;11}` which may need to be a comma.

Answer (score 1):

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> and access to dynamic formulas then try below-

```
=FILTER(A1:B11,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A11,UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A11,B1:B11="A")),0)))
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but what if those two colums arent sequential? Like i have the IDs in column B and the values in column L?